# How to correctly make many calls from Github API in Angular?

Tags: angular, github-api

I'm struggling with getting to understand **why Github API works with Postman** but not in my **Angular app**.

It works for example with

```
const url = `${this.apiBaseUrl}/orgs/angular/public_members?page=${pageNumber}`
```

even if there are multiple pages.

The code for the above URL is:

```
 getContributors(pageNumber): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.apiBaseUrl}/orgs/angular/public_members?page=${pageNumber}`;
    const requestOptions = this.getRequestOptions();

    return this.http.get(url, requestOptions);
  }
```

However, when using

```
 const url = `${this.apiBaseUrl}/users/${user}`;
```

(note it's a different endpoint /users), **more than 1 time** (literally, it works only once - occasionally twice), most calls stay on hold (in Chrome I get: `Provisional headers are shown` )

The code for the above URL is:

```
getContributor(login): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.apiBaseUrl}/users/${login}`;
    const requestOptions = this.getRequestOptions();

    return this.http.get(url, requestOptions).timeout(30000)
      .catch(error => Observable.of({
        login,
        error,
      }));
  }
```

and `getRequestOptions()` is defined as:

```
const readonlyToken = MY_API_TOKEN;
const headers = new Headers({
  // 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  Accept: '*/*',
  Authorization: `token ${readonlyToken}`,
});

  return new RequestOptions({ headers });
}
```

What I noticed is that my REST client (here I used Postman as an example, in this specific case I used Webstorm's one), `Cache-Control` works whereas with Angular I get `Cache-Control header not allowed in preflight requests`

Clearly, trying that in Postman, it works.
Now, I am not sure the issue is Github API but this half-working situation is hard to debug. Suggestions are welcome!

I've been trying to delay the requests but even with `Observable's delay`  operator it just seems not work (I use the operator with `ngrx/effects`).
I cannot share the complete code.

**UPDATE**: as I suspected, **not batching** the API calls (i.e. each every 1 seconds) works. However, this doesn't solve the original issue

Comment: I thought that the original issue was that you couldn't make several requests to github. What is the original issue then?

Comment: Exactly, I cannot make multiple requests because if they're batched they all fail (except a few). Is it clear now?

Comment: Don't batch them? Have you read https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting?

Comment: @JBNizet the problem is not the rate and I'm authenticated. The problem seems in fact to be the frequency of the calls. if I make them every 1s it just works and rate limit are per-hour

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/best-practices-for-integrators/#dealing-with-abuse-rate-limits

Comment: @JB Nizet thanks that looks like the answer I was looking for